# How many parameters can have a relative elliptical arc in SVG?

Tags: svg, path, w3c

Checking [this SVG icon](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/develop/icons/500px.svg), I can see that the third command of `d` `path` attribute it's:

`a2.993 2.993 0 0 0 2.99 2.99 2.994 2.994 0 0 0 2.99-2.99 2.993 2.993 0 0 0-2.99-2.99`

Can be rendered without problems, but I'm trying to unsertand the command. Seeing the [SVG 2 W3C specification about curve elliptical paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) I've noticed that paths can have an idetermined number of arguments (`(rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y)+`), but this parameters are not documented from the eight.

So my questions are quite simple:

- What are this parameters? (`+` from eight onwards)
- How many of them can be defined in a valid `d` attribute?
- Are documented in another source?

Comment: If after an arc ( `a` command) you have another arc (also  `a` command) the second command can be omitted. The same happens for all commands except for the move to m, M. In this case if the following command is missing is considered that the next command is a line to L

Comment: Documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData *The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the same command is used multiple times in a row*

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Likewise, I found an "a" path command with only 5 parameters, that draws a perfect circle. How does this work? This is the svg script: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<path fill="none" stroke="red" 

d=" M 200 100 a 20 20 0 110 0.1" 

/>

</svg>

Comment: If the command is an "a" in lowercase it means that is a relative command. The 5 parameters in this case are `x-axis-rotation` `large-arc-flag` `sweep-flag` `x` and  `y`, and the source coordinate (`rx` and `ry`) is taken from the last point coordinate in the previous command (in this case  `200` and `100`).

Comment: @user2707695 , actually it's `a 20 20 0 1 1 0 0.1` because parameter 4th and 5th are booleans (0 or 1) so they and the following 6th parameter (x coordinate) can be condensed this weirdly. space before a minus sign and the single zero before decimal points are also optional.

Answer (score 0):

Comments have answered already but each arc has exactly seven parameters. So if there are 14 parameters, that means there are two arcs in a row, if there are 21 parameters, that means there are three arcs and so on. It's always a multiple of seven.

Comment: You're right, but I highly recommend to improve your answer by adding a running snippet to illustrate your point.